ADB failed to connect after updating Mac OS Version to Sequoia
daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/7q/vrphc65x7_df5hj0rvpnhcv00000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 16908
--- adb starting (pid 16908) ---
09-24 11:08:25.830 16908 92226 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
09-24 11:08:25.830 16908 92226 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Version 35.0.1-11580240
09-24 11:08:25.830 16908 92226 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Installed as /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
09-24 11:08:25.830 16908 92226 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Running on Darwin 24.0.0 (arm64)
09-24 11:08:25.830 16908 92226 I adb     : main.cpp:63 
09-24 11:08:26.347 16908 92226 F adb     : main.cpp:163 could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use


Sequoia is known for it's network problems. In my opinion it is still beta, installation is not recommended at the moment for productive systems.

I had the same issue, then tried to give Android Studio & adb Full disk access (System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access).
Once done that adb worked perfectly, even after removing the access.
